# I want to loop through an item to create an array then store it in array field in the DB. How do I do it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am receiving some values from body and I want to create an array using the values and then store the array in a db

```
exports.creatVerification = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const date = req.body.dateVerified;
  const [duration] = req.body;
  const dueDates = [];
  const generateDates = (dates, period) => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= period; i + 1) {
      dueDates.push(
        moment(dates).add(i, 'months').add(1, 'days').toISOString()
      );
    }
  };
  generateDates(date, duration);

  const data = {
    investment: req.body.investment,
    topUp: req.body.topUp,
    verified: req.body.verified,
    verifiedBy: req.body.verifiedBy,
    dateVerified: req.body.dateVerified,
    dueDates,
    note: req.body.note,
  };
  console.log(data);
  const newVerify = await Verify.create(data);

  res.status(201).json(newVerify);
});
```

Here is the Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const verifySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    investment: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Investment',
    },
    topup: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'TopUp',
    },
    verified: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
    },
    verifiedBy: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Auth',
    },
    dateVerified: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now(),
      required: true,
    },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    dueDates: [Date],
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

const Verify = mongoose.model('Verify', verifySchema);

module.exports = Verify;
```

This is the verify schema which contains all the data. Also, when I try to data using react, it doesnt store on the database but when I use postman, it stores.

Comment: Can you add your schema definition for `Verify`?

Comment: @eol I have added the schema definition....

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `dueDates` to be an array of `Date`s, but you pass strings, since in your loop you do `moment(dates).add(i, 'months').add(1, 'days').toISOString()`. Removing `.toISOString()` should fix the issue:

```
dueDates.push(moment(dates).add(i, 'months').add(1, 'days'));
```

EDIT:

Just tested it on my local machine, and it seems it works either way, so `.toISOString()` is not the issue here. `i + 1` (it should be `i=i+1` or `i++`) in the for loop might be the issue, as your loop will run forever. Also you're not extracting the duration correctly, it should be:

```
const { duration } = req.body;
```

instead of

```
const [duration] = req.body;
```

Comment: It still returns an empty array. {
    "dateVerified": "2020-12-12T00:00:00.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2020-12-07T10:46:54.624Z",
    "dueDates": [],
    "_id": "5fce0825f13ced0a91a53950",
    "verified": true,
    "verifiedBy": "5fcc8739b926611a541a5baf",
    "investment": "5fcde10d1ec7da05d54942ed",
    "__v": 0,
    "id": "5fce0825f13ced0a91a53950"
}

Comment: Weird, I can't seem to reproduce this on my machine. I'll have to investigate some more.

Comment: Is `i + 1` in the for-loop a typo? it should be `i=i+1` or `i++` ...

Comment: I am having unnecessary issues with my code. Where data sent correctly isnt stored into the database even though it reaches the actions (redux). instead it stores an empty object and shows some validation error if the data in the database is requires. What can I do??

Comment: Can you answer my question regarding the loop? Also what does `req.body` contain? It looks to be that the loop is never executed as the condition `i <= period` is false ...

Comment: this is req.body {
    "verified": true,
    "dateVerified": "2020-12-12",
    "verifiedBy": "5fcc8739b926611a541a5baf",
    "investment": "5fcde10d1ec7da05d54942ed",
    "duration": 6
}